# How can I tell where the `<type 'something'>` was declared?

Tags: python, built-in, object-type, squish

I am writing automatic tests for an application using Squish framework. In test script there is code calling `randrange`:

```
a = 5.0
random.randrange( int(a) )
```

As a result of this call I get on line `lib/python2.6/random.py:171` a really bizzare error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'int'
```

Context in random.py, line 171 is the first line of code in the `randrange` function:

```
def randrange(self, start, stop=None, step=1, int=int, default=None,
              maxwidth=1L<<BPF):
    """Choose a random item from range(start, stop[, step]).

    This fixes the problem with randint() which includes the
    endpoint; in Python this is usually not what you want.
    Do not supply the 'int', 'default', and 'maxwidth' arguments.
    """

    # This code is a bit messy to make it fast for the
    # common case while still doing adequate error checking.
    istart = int(start)    # <---this is line 171
    if istart != start:
        raise ValueError, "non-integer arg 1 for randrange()"
    if stop is default:
        ...
```

Of course I checked with the debugger console, the type indeed is `int`:

```
>>> __builtin__.type(start)
<type 'int'>
>>>
```

After a while of googling I got the answer in Squish API documentation:

> Python programmers should be aware that integer type conversions such
>   as `int(x)` will not work; use `x = cast(x, int)` or `x = cast(x, "int")`
>   instead. Or if you prefer, do `import __builtin__`, and then use `x =
>   __builtin__.int(x)`. (This is necessary because Squish implements its own `int` object in Python.)

So, OK. But my question is: How to check in Python object type if there is a name conflict? How can I tell where the `<type 'something'>` was declared?

Comment: Why not just use `import __builtin__`, then `random.randrange(__builtin__.int(a))` here? That'll work fine for regular Python and Squish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to trace the origin of `int`, test for its behaviour:

```
import __builtin__

if not isinstance(int('0'), __builtin__.int):
    # uhoh, Squish replaced `int()` with a thoroughly broken version
    # replace it back for this module
    int = __builtin__.int
```

Comment: right, it's better to check with `isinstance` than with `__builtin__.type`

Comment: The redefined meaning of `int` is actually [mentioned in the Squish documentation](http://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rgs-py.html#squish.int).

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: I searched for that info when I wrote this answer; I'm not sure that that documentation was available a year ago.